# Use Python pymssql from Ubuntu bash

Tags: python, sql-server, bash, ubuntu, pymssql

I have installed Ubuntu bash on my Windows 10

I can access python3 from there, and everything seems ok

the problem i am facing at the moment is connect to MS SQL Server through Python pymssql.

I can connect from my Spyder perfectly but when I use the same script in Ubuntu bash I get this error

```
>>> conn = pymssql.connect(server="MyServer", database="MyDB")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/pymssql.pyx", line 636, in pymssql.connect
  File "src/_mssql.pyx", line 1957, in _mssql.connect
  File "src/_mssql.pyx", line 676, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.__init__
  File "src/_mssql.pyx", line 1683, in _mssql.maybe_raise_MSSQLDatabaseException
_mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (20002, b'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (MyServer:1433)\n')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "src/pymssql.pyx", line 642, in pymssql.connect
pymssql.OperationalError: (20002, b'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (MyServer:1433)\n')
```

Anyone has an idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem

I cannot access SQL DB with Windows Authentication

I used a User ID and Pwd to fix that

```
conn = pymssql.connect(server="MyServer", database="MyDB", port="1433", user="MyUser", password="MyPwd")
```

Answer (score 0):

It look like problem with libraries for Unix ( this happend to me in Debian ) .I'm not sure you can try some similar this :

**install openssl**

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install openssl
- sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

**install FreeTDS with ssl**

- wget ftp://ftp.freetds.org/pub/freetds/stable/freetds-1.00.9.tar.gz
- gunzip freetds-1.00.9.tar.gz
- tar -xvf freetds-1.00.9.tar
- cd freetds-1.00.9.tar
- sudo ./configure --with-openssl='/usr/lib/ssl'
- sudo make
- sudo make install
- Install pymssql from source with a flag to not use bundled FreeTDS
- export PYMSSQL_DONT_BUILD_WITH_BUNDLED_FREETDS=1
- sudo -H pip install git+https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql.git

**Install pymssql**

- export PYMSSQL_DONT_BUILD_WITH_BUNDLED_FREETDS=1
- sudo -H pip install git+https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql.git

Good luck